# How to store data in browser which can access by two domains

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser, cross-domain

Guys anyone know how to save data inside client machine that can access anytime?? I tried cookies, cache but they all depend on domains. I just want to save bit of data from one html file and read that data from another html. please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie should work, I would think.  The access domain part is optional when setting your cookie.